# Is there a method like .replace() for list in python?

Tags: python, string, list, methods

i've made a list out of a string using .split() method. 
For example: string = " I like chicken" i will use .split() to make a list of words in the string `['I','like','chicken']`
Now if i want to replace 'chicken' with something else, what method i can use that is like .replace() but for a list?

Answer (score 28):

There’s nothing built-in, but it’s just a loop to do the replacement in-place:

```
for i, word in enumerate(words):
    if word == 'chicken':
        words[i] = 'broccoli'
```

or a shorter option if there’s always exactly one instance:

```
words[words.index('chicken')] = 'broccoli'
```

or a list comprehension to create a new list:

```
new_words = ['broccoli' if word == 'chicken' else word for word in words]
```

any of which can be wrapped up in a function:

```
def replaced(sequence, old, new):
    return (new if x == old else x for x in sequence)


new_words = list(replaced(words, 'chicken', 'broccoli'))
```

Answer (score 4):

No such method exists, but a list comprehension can be adapted to the purpose easily, no new methods on `list` needed:

```
words = 'I like chicken'.split()
replaced = ['turkey' if wd == "chicken" else wd for wd in words]
print(replaced)
```

Which outputs: `['I', 'like', 'turkey']`