# Replace string within a list that's NOT equal to a value in Python

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list contains different names:

```
list = ['Tom', 'Mary', 'Robin', 'Tom']
```

What I want to do, is to replace `'Tom'` with `'MESSAGE'` and everyone else as `'RESPONSE'`.

Like below:
`list = ['MESSAGE', 'RESPONSE', 'RESPONSE', 'MESSAGE']`

Is there a way to do it? Preferably using only one line of code.

Answer (score 4):

It's a simple list comprehension:

```
["MESSAGE" if name == "Tom" else "RESPONSE" for name in list]
```

As a side note, do not use built-ins such as `list` to name your variables.

Answer (score 1):

Its a try, and its in a single Line. If the list contains only 2 unique values, then

```
replacedList = ['MESSAGE' if item == 'Tom' else 'RESPONSE' for item in list]
```

reference from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43107251/is-there-a-method-like-replace-for-list-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
list = ["MESSAGE" if item == "Tom" else "RESPONSE" for item in list]
```